# Content Security Policy Error for Google Visualizer

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to use google chart api in my web application. For this, I have included the following line in my html.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" defer></script>
```

I am able to load the charts in Internet Explorer, however in Chrome I am getting the following error in console.

```
Refused to load the script 'https://www.google.com/jsapi' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js".
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

It was the content security policy that was set in the application (via web.config in my case).

The solution is to modify the policy in either
1. web.config (to apply for the who;e application) or
2. Add the header to response for this particular case.